# Delete multiple entities by id Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is there a more efficient way of deleting multiple entities by id

```
$data = $this->request->data ['missing_lexicon_id'];
foreach ( $data as $id ) {
    $missingLexicon = $this->MissingLexicons->get ( $id );
    $this->MissingLexicons->delete ( $missingLexicon )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
$this->MissingLexicons->deleteAll(['MissingLexicons.column IN' => $keys]);
```

Where $keys is an array with the ids to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to delete multiple entities using [deleteALL()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#bulk-deletes).

```
$this->MissingLexicons->deleteAll(['id IN' => $multiItemsArray]);
```

**OR**

```
$this->MissingLexicons->deleteAll(['id' => $multiItemsArray[]]);
```

> MissingLexicons = Your Model name.
>
> $multiItemsArray = Your deleted entities id

[Read More Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#bulk-deletes)